# JQuery Get command and eventually PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, cordova

Ive been making a site that interacts with a Java Servlet to get data.
And its been going really well. Im running tomcat to run the site.

So at the moment im getting data like this:

$.get('data',{some parameters}, function(data) {
  do stuff...
});

Ive also changed the 'data' to 'MYIP:8080/WebPortal/data' and it still works fine.

But anything seems to only work if I go to 'MYIP:8080/WebPortal/index.html' in my browser rather than just opening the index.html file on its own. This wasn't really an issue until I started thinking using a Phonegap App to get data in the same way.

I assumed making the url of the servlet absolute would make it aok but phonegap behaves just like opening the .html file straight up, which *is* what its supposed to do.

Ive heard about crossdomain policies and Phonegap's white list but I dont really understand them fully yet and dont know if they are relevant here.

So if anyone knows why my jquery commands only work through a server would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a globally visble ip? First try changing that MYIP to localhost:8080 and then check if just opening "index.html" works.

If it happens than it means that your IP is not globally visible... and that's causing the problems.

Comment: Yeah I was about to type I tried 'localhost:8080/WebPortal/index.html' as well and it is still the same result, typing in the whole url works but opening the file doesnt. I also have my port 8080 forwarded and using myexternalip:8080/etc works.